# SCSS - Different parents - same tag simplification

Tags: sass

I have this navigation in HTML that looks like following:

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-item lvl-0">
    <a></a>
    <div class="sub">
      <div class="nav-item lvl-1">
        <a></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have some styles applied to all `a`s in the navigation in the defaults layer, now I want to add separate styles for each level. I have this

```scss
nav {
    .nav-item {
        a {padding:0;}
        &.lvl-0 {
            > a {@extend .size-18;}
        }

        &.lvl-1 {
            > a {@extend .size-13;}
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to write something along these lines:

```scss
nav {
    .nav-item {
        a {padding:0; 
            .lvl-0 > & {@extend .size-18;}
            .lvl-1 > & {@extend .size-13;}
        }
    }
}
```